# Chrome Extension Manifest v3 Service Worker MediaRecorder Alternative

Tags: google-chrome, mediarecorder, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, browser-extension

I have chrome extension (written in Manifest v2) that uses MediaRecorder to record the web session

In background.js I have below code to capture web session

```
 chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {format: 'png', quality: 100},
    function(base64) {
       // base64 is used to write to the canvas 
       // and used canvas.getMediaStream() to get the stream 
       // and stream passed as input to mediaRecorder
    });
```

now I have to migrate to Manifest v3 where service worker don't have access to mediaRecorder and I am looking for alternative to it.

I have also tried to send base64 to the content script to write it onto canvas and to use canvas stream and media recorder available on the content script, but as and when page refreshes stream ends and new canvas and stream get created which causes video played in different tracks.

please let me know if anyone has solution for it

Comment: You can do it inside a chrome-extension:// iframe in the web page. The iframe should be exposed via `web_accessible_resources`.

Comment: If I create Iframe within the webpage with eg. chrome-extension://xxxxx/capture.html url and if page reload Iframe will also reload, how can I continue the same stream

Am I getting it correctly?

Comment: Then open a new window using chrome.windows.create...